# Checkboxes to select multiple records and create new association records if not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models (user, review, and period). What I would like to do is to have checkboxes in **user index view** where I can select multiple users (or all) and click a "Create Review" button where upon clicking, it will:

1. Check if the selected users have a **review** record and if not create one for all selected users.
2. Also this will also update the review record with the period_id of '1'

I'm not sure on how to go about this and any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :periods, :through => :reviews

  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :username, :first_name, :last_name, :role
end
```

review.rb

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :period

  attr_accessible :employee_comments, :employee_final_comments, :manager_comments, :period_id, :rating, :review_status, :user_id
end
```

period.rb

```
class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, :through => :reviews

  attr_accessible :admin_id, :end_date, :period_name, :start_date, :active
end
```

**Update 1**

I've added the following lines into my index.html.erb (based on railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple)), but getting a blank list. If I remove the form_tag line, I can see the list of users with the checkboxes.

app/views/users/index.html.erb

```
<% form_tag create_multiple_users_path do %>
  .
  .
  .
  <th><%= check_box_tag "users_ids[]", user.id %></th>
<% end %>
  .
  .
  .
<%= submit_tag "Create Reviews for selected users" %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    post 'create_multiple'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of users using the form you should change

```
<% form_tag create_multiple_users_path do %>
```

for

```
 <%= form_tag create_multiple_users_path do %>
```